# Why can't I select a database? (Error 'No Database Selected')

Tags: php, mysql, database, calendar

I found this nifty PHP calendar which did exactly what I was trying to create so I decided to adopt it onto my website. The problem however is I can not for the life of me get it working...

Here is the code for the functions [here](http://www.rpetechnologies.com/calendar/code.php?p=c). And [here](http://www.rpetechnologies.com/calendar/code.php?p=h) is the generic page. My dbinfo.php looks like this.

```
<?php

$dbhost = 'localhost';

$dbuser = 'username';

$dbpass = 'pass';

$dbname = 'database';

$dblink = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname);

?>
```

Can anyone offer me some assistance.

Comment: and then `mysql_select_db($dbname)`

Answer (score 0):

$dblink = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);
mysql_select_db($dbname);

Answer (score 0):

After you connect to your database with `mysql_connect()`, you have to call [`mysql_select_db()`](http://php.net/mysql_select_db) to select a database.

Try the following:

```
$dblink = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);
mysql_select_db($dbname, $dblink);
```

Side note (not answer specific):
You should consider using the [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) libraries instead of the outdated/unsupported `mysql_` methods. Both provide you with additional features and security benefits and modifying your code to implement either is not too difficult. For instance, the same code as above, but with MySQLi would be:

```
$dblink = mysqli_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname);
```

Note here that you can select the database in the same call as the connection itself!

Comment: mysql_connect doesn't take the db name as a fourth parameter.

Comment: @Arnaud Sorry, was typing-ahead to do the `mysqli` example; thanks for catching that.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing it the wrong way.

Try:

`$db_link = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);`

And Then:

`mysql_select_db($dbname);`

However, using mysql_* functions is discouraged now. Use MySQLi or PDO instead.

Comment: Ahh, thank you! Yes, I'll be converting it over to MySQLi. I just wanted to solve the problem I had with it first. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

`mysql_connect` is deprecated http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php

You should use mysqli or PDO if possible. Try `mysqli_connect` instead.
Plus look at Xingjia Luo answer, the your last argument (dbName) should not be passed.

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.dual-interface.php

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
$con = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbusername, $dbpassword);
mysql_select_db($yourdb, $con);
```